# Sphinx returns old data after indexer --rotate

Tags: search-engine, sphinx

I'm having sphinx version 2.0.4 fully working.

Whenever I want to reindex data, I'm using indexer

```
/usr/bin/indexer --config /etc/sphinxsearch/sphinx.conf XXX --rotate
```

It gives output:

```
root@dsphinx:~# /usr/bin/indexer --config /etc/sphinxsearch/sphinx.conf XXX --rotate 

using config file '/etc/sphinxsearch/sphinx.conf'...
indexing index 'XXX'...
collected 9536 docs, 55.8 MB
sorted 4.7 Mhits, 100.0% done
WARNING: 2 duplicate document id pairs found
total 9536 docs, 55758410 bytes
total 3.930 sec, 14187197 bytes/sec, 2426.34 docs/sec
total 4 reads, 0.005 sec, 2926.5 kb/call avg, 1.3 msec/call avg
total 262 writes, 0.062 sec, 311.5 kb/call avg, 0.2 msec/call avg
rotating indices: succesfully sent SIGHUP to searchd (pid=14068).
```

The problem is that process 14068 gives old indexed data.

If I reload service (`/etc/inid.d/sphinxsearch reload`) this process ID is changed and sphinx returns new indexed data.

Is this a bug or I'm not doing something right?

Answer (score 1):

How are you running queries?

Are you using any sort of persistant connection manager in your client? If so, it might be holding connections open, that doesnt give searchd a chance to actully restart.

(ie the restart will be delayed until all connections are closed)

Comment: That was my first thought. Well, it's not constant connections and cached stayed with server for 3 months and netstats don't show any connections